# unable to ready marathi language come from json response in android application

Tags: android, google-input-tools

I am developing android application for marathi language. I want retrive marathi data from asp.net server. I am using google marathi input for storing the data in server , but in client side (android application) unable to read the marathi font. Not all characters are human readable.
Please suggest an answer to overcome this problem of unknown characters in android application.

[image: Here is the sample image from my device]

Answer (score 0):

By default not all languages supported by Android Framework,
If you really want to show any language except English you can use unicode .